# Include Parent Term in wp_list_categories

Tags: php, terms, categories

I am using the script below to list the custom taxonomies, but I still need a link to the parent of the current custom taxonomy for an "All" link.

Right now the links display as:

Shoes Shirt T-Shirt

Would like to include an "All" link so it will display as:

All Shoes Shirt T-Shirt

```
<?php       

$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
$children = get_term_children( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy );
echo get_category_link( get_queried_object_id() );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $children ) && ! empty( $children ) ) {
wp_list_categories( 'taxonomy=' . $term->taxonomy . '&depth=1&show_count=0&title_li='. $title.'&child_of=' . $term->term_id );
} else {
wp_list_categories( 'taxonomy=' . $term->taxonomy . '&depth=1&show_count=0&title_li=&child_of=' . $term->parent );
} ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, which worked well for me:

```php
$term = get_queried_object();
$children = get_term_children( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy );
$has_children = ( ! is_wp_error( $children ) && ! empty( $children ) );

// Has children, or no parent.
if ( $has_children || ! $term->parent ) {
    $parent =& $term; // reference to $term
// No children, but has parent.
} elseif ( $term->parent ) {
    // Get the term object (or data like name) using get_term().
    $parent = get_term( $term->parent );
}

echo '<h3><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $parent ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $parent->name ) . '</a></h3>';
wp_list_categories( 'taxonomy=' . $term->taxonomy . '&depth=1&show_count=0&title_li=&child_of=' . $parent->term_id );
```

**Explanation/Notes:**

- On a taxonomy archive, you should use `get_queried_object()` to get the.. queried term — just like when you visit a single post page, `get_queried_object()` would give you the queried post.
- You can use [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) to get the term archive URL (e.g. `http://example.com/category/uncategorized`).
- I intentionally didn't use the `title_li` parameter because you're only displaying level 1 children (i.e. you set the `depth` parameter to `1`).

And I used the `h3` tag, but you can of course change it to your liking. :)

Comment: Worked perfect, I just removed the "esc_html( $parent->name )" and replaced that with all, and formatted it properly to blend right in. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: 2 for 2 Sally, you're on fire!

Comment: I look forward to make it 3! ;)